# Migrating a whole website between Craft instances

Tags: database, migration, upgrades

A developer built our site locally configured as "craft.dev". At the same time, my sysadmin was busy getting Craft installed with Apache on our Linux server. He set that up with our real domain and purchased the $299 license for "ourcoolwebsite.com".

Now we've got the real website on the developer's machine, and a blank website on the linux server.

**What files/folders do we need to migrate to get the real website up?** Should we just dump and load his database and overwrite the one that was created for the install? I am guessing there are some database tables with data specific to my purchase and license key that differ from his. Basically I want to know how to take his work and put it into my production environment with database tables and file paths.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Make sure both Craft installs are up-to-date.
2. [Craft's license](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/transferring-purchases) is saved in `craft/config/license.key`, make a backup of your purchased license file.
3. Move all your files/directories except:

   > /craft/app/
   >   /craft/storage/
4. Copy the backup of your `license.key` to `craft/config/`.
5. Remove `/craft/storage/`, if it exists on your new server, to prevent cache errors.
6. "dump and load" your database to the new server. Craft will update what's necessary.
7. Update your [config settings](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings) in `/craft/config/`.
8. Go to your BackEnd.

Also you might find this interesting:

[What's the best practice for handling data migration and organization across development environments?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/10/177)

Comment: Thanks Victor for the information here - this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: The only trouble I had with the explanation above was that user photos are stored in the `craft/storage/userphotos` directory. So, you'll lose these photos if you completely omit the `storage` directory. In my case, I only lost the photo for the admin and just updated it on the live site. In the case where there are more users with existing user photos this might be more of a concern. Maybe @Victor In or someone else can comment if uploading the `craft/storage/userphotos` directory from the development site would cause caching issues?

Answer (score 3):

Your purchase on the "real" domain was tied to your the `craft/config/license.key` file on that site.

All you should need to do is move your files up *except* for your local development `license.key` file, restore the database to the production site and adjust any domains/paths as necessary.

Comment: Also overwrite the local license.key with the one from the "real" domain, so you don't screw yourself later.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful to anyone searching here as well: [Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms)