# How to create a migration for the main Craft DB?

Tags: database, migration

Let's say we add a section or other elements (field, category, tags, assets, etc) in the CP on our dev servers and want to roll that change out to a stage or production environment, is there a way to capture the changes we've made through the CP as a migration, or is there some other recommended way to reverse engineer that into a migration?

I have checked out the documentation on creating [plugin migrations](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/migrations) and a couple of questions [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/migrating-a-whole-website-between-craft-instances) and [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev), but nothing addressing creating a migration for the craft DB itself.

Comment: Already answered here:
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev/14148#14148

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the answer to a complicated problem. :)

What you're thinking of I would describe as "content migrations" or "content model syncing".

There is currently nothing in Craft out-of-the-box that will do what you're looking for, although we've got some ideas on how we'd like to approach the sharing/syncing of content between environments/installations in the long term.

If you need something before then, you'll have to write a plugin that rolls its own solution.

Comment: I really think addressing this in the core of Craft would truly separate it head and shoulders from other CMSs. My hope is that this is addressed sooner than later and is a high priority for the Pixel and Tonic team. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Brad We are not worried about the user content per se. I assume you are calling it a 'contents migration' because of the nature of craft, and how all fields, elements, etc are both structural (i.e. change the schema) as well as content (i.e. add records to `craft_elements`, `craft_fields`, etc.)?

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald Exactly.

Comment: @BradBell are there any recommended plugins that do this now (2017)?