# What's the easiest way to migrate my local site data to my live site?

Tags: database, migration

I've finished my site locally, and would like to migrate my data to my production database.

I've already uploaded the templates, assets, etc, but I'm unsure how to 'dump and load' (referenced from [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/migrating-a-whole-website-between-craft-instances) ) my database to production.

I realize this may be a little bit more phpMyAdmin related, but I thought this question could help others who are just beginning work with Craft CMS!

Answer (score 4):

1. Go into Utilities
2. Click "Database Backup", this will give you a .zip file of your data
3. Go into phpMyAdmin of your production site
4. Find your database, click Import
5. Upload .zip file

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I'd suggest a more holistic approach, such as the one described in my article [Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms)

It'll make your long-term workflow much easier.