# How to export client-entered content for a specific channel to keep my local database in sync with staging

Tags: database, workflow

I'm in the process of developing a site for a client and I'd like to give them access to the control panel on the staging server so they can begin to enter content for their "News" channel, which is set up and ready to go, and for which they have lots of historical content to enter.

The issue is that I'm still developing the rest of the site and want to come up with the most painless way possible of keeping their content in-tact in the database without breaking my development workflow as I continue to create additional fields and templates for the remaining sections of the site.

Is there a way that I can easily export just their "News" channel content from the staging database periodically, importing it into my local database and eventually migrating my more complete local database back to staging as I finish more sections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently not an easy or clean answer for this.

There are some [great answers here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev) on different solutions for handling data syncing/migrations across multiple environments.

We've got some ideas of our own on how we'd like to make this less painful for users (it's a PITA for us as well), with syncing / importing / exporting data between Craft installs, but unfortunately we don't have an ETA on it.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link Brad. Glad to hear P&T is thinking about it.

Comment: Are you still thinking about it? Been seven years.