# Exporting Entry content

Tags: entries, content

I really spend a lot of time searching for a solution to this problem.  When I try using the [Export plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/export) to export some entries with some Matrix fields and Neo fields for content, all that I can get is empty.

Seems to me that no one could've resolved the problem "[Exporting / Importing all translatable Textfields of all entries in a section](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20910/exporting-importing-all-translatable-textfields-of-all-entries-in-a-section)" or "[How to export client-entered content for a specific channel to keep my local database in sync with staging](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/how-to-export-client-entered-content-for-a-specific-channel-to-keep-my-local-dat)" which my problem is similar to.  I tried to search in the database for the content of the entry added by the client, found it and I'm working on how to replace it in my DB without causing errors, but the relation between tables still confuses me.

So my questions are, is there any solution yet? If not do I need to create a plugin that read Matrix fields and export it as JSON data? Do I continue in my attempts in the database to try and find the entries and their related content (is it possible)?

I hope I have explained enough clearly my situation.

P.S : I'm still a novice in Craft CMS so take it easy on me ^^

Comment: If you were not able to find a solution I might help you but I was still not able to understand what your goal is. Do you just want to sync your database automatically? Or do you want to create something like a json file just to have the data? I created an excel export for craft few months ago so I know it's pretty easy so export entries but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Because if it's just about a one time export and import into your database you can just dump his database and include it in your system

Comment: My goal is to export entries that containts only matrix, neo, supertable fileds that the export plugins  don't support, the neo and supertable fields are inside the matrix field, so to be able to recover data from other envirenement, i need to export only to the contents just like the export plugin only with this cutomized version of field.
So am I claire enough now ? thanks again for the reply.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question / the most important thing: the format of the data. If it does not matter I would say make a sql dump and that's it

Comment: i can't just export data as sql form, i might have an ID conflict with the other database, so if i have to chose the format of the data, JSON it is.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check out the Sprout Reports plugin? I've used it to export matrix field data.