# How do you manage master db across multiple environments?

Tags: database

I've just started my first Craft site locally and it's all good so far.. a little further down the road, I'll need to then deploy regularly to integration/test/stage and production environments.

I'm just wondering how people manage DB syncing across these different environments?

Answer (score 2):

See carlcs' comment. [What's the best practice for handling data migration and organization across development environments?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev) is one of the biggest discussions on this S/E.