# Database: Syncing "craft_fields" table through SQL dumps not possible?

Tags: matrix, database, field, migration, workflow

I've been trying to simply sync an addition to a matrix field building block from my local dev server to the live environment database by doing a SQL dump of the "craft_fields" table. I now have the same entry appearing in the remote database, however in the CP fields setup the additional field is not showing up in that particular matrix field.

What am I doing wrong? Or in other words: How can I optimize the workflow without having to do everything twice, in each CP (dev/live), for each field added later in the project's process?

Manually adding fields in both CPs is very prone to errors …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to develop a workflow where you have one database (usually `live` production or `staging`) where all changes are made, and then sync down the database/assets from there.

Adding this concept of which server is the "source of truth" will greatly simplify keeping things in sync.

[Craft-Scripts](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts) are a collection of shell scripts that help you do just that. All of this is discussed in detail in the article [Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms)

Answer (score 1):

> Manually adding fields in both CPs is very prone to errors …

Yes, but probably less error prone that the method you're doing now. :)

Field information is stored in more than the `craft_fields` table.  For example, most field content is saved in `craft_content`, but Matrix fields get their entire own tables to store Matrix content, which has dynamic rows and columns based on Matrix field settings and Matrix data.

But even then `craft_matrixblocks` and `craft_matrixblocktypes` might change depending on what has been done.  And data might have been added to `craft_relations` if the Matrix field had any relational fields in it (Users, Entries, Assets, Categories, etc.).

It's a complicated problem (moving schema and data changes in Craft between environments) that [Content Migrations](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-content-migrations) in the upcoming Craft 3 takes a baby step towards solving and one we hope to address long-term in the future.

Some further reading: [What's the best practice for handling data migration and organization across development environments?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10/whats-the-best-practice-for-handling-data-migration-and-organization-across-dev/15#15)